# Trying to hide labels on button if color is red in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This will only work for the labels sender but, I need to use this also for the button sender so it can hide if the label is red only when the button is clicked. 
I have 48 Seats
Private Sub Label_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Seat9.Click, Seat8.Click, Seat7.Click, Seat6.Click, Seat5.Click, Seat48.Click, Seat47.Click, Seat46.Click, Seat45.Click, Seat44.Click, Seat43.Click, Seat42.Click, Seat41.Click, Seat40.Click, Seat4.Click, Seat39.Click, Seat38.Click, Seat37.Click, Seat36.Click, Seat35.Click, Seat34.Click, Seat33.Click, Seat32.Click, Seat31.Click, Seat30.Click, Seat3.Click, Seat29.Click, Seat28.Click, Seat27.Click, Seat26.Click, Seat25.Click, Seat24.Click, Seat23.Click, Seat22.Click, Seat21.Click, Seat20.Click, Seat2.Click, Seat19.Click, Seat18.Click, Seat17.Click, Seat16.Click, Seat15.Click, Seat14.Click, Seat13.Click, Seat12.Click, Seat11.Click, Seat10.Click, Seat1.Click

```
Dim Seats As Label = CType(sender, Label)

    If Seats.BackColor = Color.White Then

        Seats.BackColor = Color.Red

    Else

        Seats.BackColor = Color.White

    End If
```

Comment: Are you capturing this event for a specific label? Can you not just use the label name instead of converting the sender? I'm struggling to understand your logic. The button should disappear when it's clicked if the label background is red? If you could explain hat you are trying to achieve, maybe we could develop a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand now. 
You have multiple labels which represent seats and when the user clicks on the labels they change from white to red. 
You are wanting to create a button that once clicked, it removes all red labels from the screen/form. 
You would place the following in the click event of your button (assuming that your form is called frmMain)

```
For Each c As Control in frmMain.Controls
 Dim l As Label = DirectCast(c, Label) ' Cast from control to label
 If Not l Is Nothing ' If this control is indeed a label then process
   If l.BackColor = Color.Red Then ' If color is red then hide label
     l.Visible = False
   Else
    l.Visible = True
   End If
  l.Visible = False
 End If
Next
```

I don't have VS pulled up, so syntax may be a little incorrect but I think you get the point.